# AWS Lambda execute code in runtime before return

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, aws-lambda-extensions

I started developing an AWS Lambda Extension (external) which uses the V8 engine code coverage. The problem with this approach is that the generated coverage seems to be for the Extension code and not for the Lambda code itself.
In order to use V8 I coverage I set the environment variable on the Lambda itself like so:
`NODE_V8_COVERAGE = '/tmp'`
This seems to work but I have to manually call:
`v8.takeCoverage();` from the extension itself in the Shutdown hook. The issue with this approach is as I mentioned above, there is not exported coverage for the Lambda but it's for the Extension itself.
Is there a way to hook into a Lambda just before/after it returns and it shuts down to call the required method and export the coverage? I need this to be a "universal" solution and not per-lambda.

I setup an environment variable on the Lambda to start collection coverage using the V8 engine native coverage:
`NODE_V8_COVERAGE = '/tmp'`
Then from the Extension code I use `v8.takeCoverage()` to export all the coverage until that point in time, but the exported file has no coverage info about the Lambda code itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.